# Number of combs returned by combn reduced by some combs in R

Tags: r, combn

I am trying to figure out how to reckon the number of combinations returned by combn function after exclusion of some selected combinations. Let's say, we have a vector c("var1","var2","var3","var4","var5") and I want to get all combinations of the elements of this one except these that consits of c("var4","var5"). Here is the code:

```
vector <- c("var1","var2","var3","var4","var5")
exclude <- matrix(c("var4","var5"),1,2)

for(i in 1:length(vector)){
  comb <- combn(vector,i)
  for(j in 1:ncol(comb)){
    newcomb <- c(comb[,j])
    if (any(as.logical("FALSE"),apply(exclude, 1, function(x) all(x %in% newcomb)))) {next}
      else {print(newcomb)}}
}
```

The number of combinations returned from combn function without any reduction is 31. It is reckoned as:

```
f <- function(nvars){
  a <- NULL
  for (i in 1:nvars){
    a[i] <- choose(nvars,i)}
  return(sum(a))}
f(5)
```

Any suggestions how to get the number of reduced combinations (for 5 variables and exclusion of combinations  that contain "var4" and "var5" at same time, it should be 23). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will calculate the number of combinations for any input `vector` and `exclude` (it is based on your loop in the question)...

```
sum(sapply(seq_along(vector),                   #sum for all combination lengths...
    function(i) sum(apply(combn(vector, i), 2,  #...the sum for all combinations...
        function(y) !any(apply(exclude, 1,      #...the value for each row of exclude...
            function(x) all(x %in% y)))))))     #...whether combn doesn't contain exclude row

[1] 71 #for the example you give
```

Comment: Thanks! This is the general solution I was after.

Comment: Do you think its worth replacing combn function with some faster alternative? I just tried to reckon the number of combinations for my data frame (~30 columns) and it will take ages to return the result. Firstly, I compute the correlation matrix (i.e. find columns that are correlated at given level) and then your piece of script is executed.

Comment: Yes, the numbers will get very big if you have that many columns. You might need to rethink what you are trying to achieve with this.

Comment: The purpose of this was to figure out how many combinations my loops (that find optimal GLM across given data frame) need to go through.

Comment: It sounds like you have a lot of variables, so that is going to take a long time! You could look at reducing the number of dimensions with something like principal component analysis, especially if there is quite a lot of correlation between variables.

Answer (score -1):

We loop through the sequence of `vector`, get the `combn` by specifying the 'm' as the sequence value, then check whether `all` the 'exclude' elements are there `%in%` the combination elements, negate (`!`), `unlist` the `list` and get the `sum` of logical elements

```
sum(unlist(lapply(seq_along(vector), function(i) combn(vector, i,
         FUN = function(x) !all(c(exclude) %in% x)))))
#[1] 23
```

Comment: n_combs <- function(){
  for(i in 1:length(vector)){
    comb <- combn(vector,i)
    for(j in 1:ncol(comb)){
      a<-sum(unlist(lapply(seq_along(vector), function(i) combn(vector, i,
         FUN = function(x) !all(c(exclude) %in% x)))))
    }
  }
  print(a)
}

n_combs()

Comment: this piece of code works but isnt it possible to get the same result by some other way? by using this code one needs to wait untill all the combinations within the nested loops are created..

Comment: @New2coding If you need the `combn` output, then it has to go through this

Comment: the f function stated above calculates unreduced number of combinations so I guess there is a way how to calculate the number of reduced combinations without a need to go through all of results given by combn. Andrew Gustar suggested: choose(nvars,i)-i*(i-1)/2 but it does not appear to return correct number of combinations.

Comment: @New2coding  It will not return the correct indices

Comment: @New2coding Sorry - that should have been `choose(nvars,i) - choose(nvars-2,i-2)`, and zero for `i=1`.  The sum will be `2^nvars - 2^(nvars-2) - 1` (i.e. 23 for `nvars=5`)

Answer (score -1):

One of the solutions I was after:

```
f <- function(x,y){
  a <- NULL
  for (i in 1:x){
    a[i] <- choose(x,i) - choose(x-y,i-y)}
  return(sum(a))}
f(5,2)
```

@Andrew Gustar - Thanks for your suggestion!

I still need to find more general solution for matrix where are variables to be excluded (some of them are distinct, some of them are not):

```
vector <- c("var1","var2","var3","var4","var5","var6","var7","var8")
exclude <- matrix(c(c("var3","var2"),c("var4","var3"),c("var5","var7")),3,2)).
```

Comment: `2^x - 2^(x-y) - 1` is probably quicker!

Comment: Do you think it can be further amended so if one has more pairs of excluded variables (e.g. exclude <- matrix(c(c("var3","var2"),c("var4","var7")),2,2)) it still works? Thanks!

Comment: The number of combinations excluding at least one of two distinct sets of y elements would presumably be `2^x - 2*2^(x-y) + 2^(x-2*y) - 1`, three distinct sets would be `2^x - 3*2^(x-y) + 3*2^(x-2*y) - 2^(x-3*y) - 1`, and so on. If the sets are not distinct (eg `var1,var2` and `var2,var3`) then it gets more complicated!

Comment: They are not distinct sets because in fact this demonstrates correlated variables so c("var1","var2") & c("var2","var3") may happen easily. I will try to figure out the formula that returns the number of combinations without these excluded.